# If $T \in L(X,X)$ is a bounded operator and $lim_{n \to \infty} ||T^n|| = 0$ then $\sigma(T) \subset B_r(0)$ for some $r < 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and let $T: X \to X$ be a bounded operator such that $lim_{n \to \infty} ||T^n|| = 0$.

I need to show that there exists $r < 1$ such that $\sigma(T) \subset \overline{B_r(0)}$.

I managed to show that if $|\lambda| \ge 1$ then $\lambda \not \in \sigma_p(T)$, because otherwise, there is some $x \in X$ with $||x|| = 1$ such that $Tx = \lambda x$ so $T^nx = \lambda ^n x$  and then $||T^n|| \ge ||T^nx|| = |\lambda|^n \ge 1$, which is a contradiction to $lim_{n \to \infty} ||T^n|| = 0$.

However, I'm not sure how to show that $\lambda \not \in \sigma_c(T)$ or $\lambda \not \in \sigma_r(T)$

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The spectral radius of an operator $T$ has the [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Upper_bound) $$\rho(T)\le\|T^n\|^{1/n}\le\|T\|$$
Hence $$\rho(T)^n\le\|T^n\|\to0$$ so $\rho(T)<1$ as required.

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps me

Comment: @GabiG Which part? If $\rho(T)<1$ then pick $r$ such that $\rho(T)<r<1$, so $\sigma(T)\subset B_r(0)$.

Comment: I don't understand how that shows that if $|\lambda| \ge 1$ then $\lambda \not \in \sigma_c(T)$ and  $\lambda \not \in \sigma_r(T)$

Comment: @GabiG If $\sigma(T)\subset B_r(0)$ then $|\lambda|\ge1\implies \lambda\notin\sigma(T)$, irrespective of $\sigma_p$ or $\sigma_c$ or $\sigma_r$.

Comment: Isn't $\rho(T)$ the largest eigenvalue? How is it enough to prove $\sigma(T) \subset B_r(0)$?

Comment: @GabiG No, $\rho(T)$ is the spectral radius, equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|T^n\|^{-1/n}$.

Comment: Still, I don't it follows that $\sigma(T) \subset B_r(0)$